# Shake: how do I depend on dynamically generated source files?

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

Given a directory structure like this:

```
.
├── frontend
│   ├── _build/          -- build dir, all files produced by shake, except for Frontend.elm, go here
│   ├── Build.hs         -- the build script
│   ├── build.sh         -- wrap Build.hs with `stack exec build -- $@`
│   ├── other files ...
│   ├── Frontend.elm     -- generated by a rule in Build.hs, `protoc  -I../proto --elm_out=. ../proto/frontend.proto`
│   ├── Index.elm        -- hand written source file
│   └── other elms ...   -- hand written source files
└── proto
    └── frontend.proto   -- protocol buffer message defination, hand written
```

Target `_build/index.js` depends on all `.elm` files, including `Frontend.elm`,
but `Frontend.elm` is generated by a rule in `Build.hs`,
if I blindly do:

```hs
want ["_build/index.js"]
"_build/index.js" %> \out -> do
    elms <- filter (not . elmStuff)
            <$> (liftIO $ getDirectoryFilesIO "" ["//*.elm"])
    need elms
    blah blah

want ["Frontend.elm"]
"Frontend.elm" %> \_out -> do
    cmd ["protoc", "blah", "blah"]
```

`build.sh clean` would give me:

```
Lint checking error - value has changed since being depended upon:
  Key:  Frontend.elm
  Old:  File {mod=0x608CAAF7,size=0x53D,digest=NEQ}
  New:  File {mod=0x608CAB5B,size=0x53D,digest=NEQ}
```

Is there a way to tell shake to watch out for the dynamically generated `Frontend.elm`, maybe build it first so it doesn't change during the rest of the build, I tried `priority 100 ("Frontend.elm" %> ...)`, doesn't work.

Comment: Can you generate Frontend.elm not in the current directory but in the _build? And can you move all source files to directory src (as example)?

Comment: @freestyle 1. no, I cannot move it to _build, because 1.1 Elm uses directory structure as module naming space and 1.2 it need to be version controlled. 2 you mean move all hand written source files to a `src`, but generated source files to somewhere else? no I cannot, because 1.1

Comment: 1.1 Usually, there is a way to specify the search path for imports. For example, the GHC has an option -i. 1.2 Also usually there is no sense in keeping the generated file in the VCS, it is enough to keep the original data for generation and the build script itself. 2 I mean restructure like this: frontend\\_build -- contains all generated files; frontend\src -- contains all source files (handwritten).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably:

1. Switch from `getDirectoryFilesIO`, which does not track changes to the file system, to `getDirectoryFiles`, which does.
2. Declare your dependence on `Frontend.elm`, which you know you need even if it does not exist in the filesystem yet (hence might not be visible to `getDirectoryFiles`).
3. (Optional) Don't bother `want`ing `Frontend.elm`, since you only wanted it as a hack to enable `_build/index.js`.

With these changes, it would look like this:

```
want ["_build/index.js"]
"_build/index.js" %> \out -> do
    need ["Frontend.elm"]
    elms <- filter (not . elmStuff)
            <$> getDirectoryFiles "" ["//*.elm"]
    need elms
    blah blah

"Frontend.elm" %> \_out -> do
    cmd ["protoc", "blah", "blah"]
```

Caveat lector: I have not tested this solution.

Comment: Here is problem. `getDirectoryFiles "" ["//*.elm"]` depends on changes in CD and Frontend.elm is generated in CD.

Comment: It is better to keep the source files (not generated) separately and separately the directory for the files that are being builded.

Comment: @freestyle Ah, right, probably I should move the `need` a bit higher to deal with that infelicity. Modification incoming.

Comment: This can still lead to a problem. Let us imagine that the Frontend.elm depends (or will be in the future) `getDirectoryFiles "" ["//*.somthingelse"]`. The shake doc talks about getDirectoryFiles: "You should only call this function returning source files".

Comment: seems I can get away with `orderOnly`

Comment: The above `need ["Frontend.elm"]` situation is exactly what `orderOnly` was designed for. That said, if you `orderOnly` something then know you will later always `need` it then it's really no benefit (or harm) in using `orderOnly` the first time.

Comment: It is safe to do `getDirectoryFiles` after `orderOnly` or `need`ing everything that might be added to the directory. I've slightly weakened the docs to say "You should normally only call..." - your case is safe.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right, but if I `orderOnly [frontendElm]` then `need everyElmsIncludingFrontendElm`, the build works, if I just `need everyElmsIncludingFrontendElm`, then it will complain.